# Set the name of second div by clicking the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new in jquery (real newbie) , but I am trying to solve a problem.
I cannot get this script to work in the desired way.
There are two divs. when you click on the second one, the first one is clicked as well.
That works for me when you have specific name for the first div.
html+css for both examples:

```
<div id ="div11" name="this-is-name-of-div" data-unique="this-is-name-of-div" style="width:100px;
```

height:100px;
background-color: blue; color:white;cursor: crosshair;">FIRST ELEMENT

SECOND ELEMENT

[working axample-jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skywalker13/G7y6F/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#div11").bind("click", (function () {
    alert("DIV11 is clicked!");
}));
$(".item").bind("click", (function () {
    $('div[name=this-is-name-of-div]').trigger("click");
    return false;
}));
});
```

The first div has the same name attribute as second div data-unique attribute. By clicking the second div I would like to set the name of div to be clicked, but under those square brackets I cannot get it work. Can somebody help me to solve this correctly? Thx in advance for help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#div11").bind("click", (function () {
    alert("DIV11 is clicked!");
}));
$(".item").bind("click", (function () {
    $('div[name=$(this).attr("data-unique")]').trigger("click");
    return false;
}));
});
```

[jsfiddle-notworking-to-achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/skywalker13/ju9H7/)
[jsfiddle-not-working-to-achieve][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var name = $(this).attr("data-unique");
$('div[name=' + name + ']').trigger("click");
```

But this could fail if `name` contains some special characters like `]`. If that's a concern, try using the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, like this:

```
var name = $(this).attr("data-unique");
$('div').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('name') == name; })
        .trigger("click");
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/KxzPT/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I've been looking for. Work as it should to.

Comment: Hello, How to solve this click event on tablets and similar? It works on mobile phones, but tablets doesn't accept this click event.

Comment: Hello @p.s.w.g, How to solve this click event on tablets and similar? It works on mobile phones, but tablets doesn't accept this click event from dropdowns. I have tried with simple script touchclick.js (https://github.com/tuxracer/jquery-touchclick) but i cannot get it operational.